# Is it safe to use CComBSTR with wcscmp function without casting?

Tags: c++, com

I have following question
Consider  following C++ code snippet

```
CComBSTR bs1=L"str1";
if (wcscmp(bs1,L"str2"))
{ 
 ....
}
```

**The question is : is it safe to use CComBSTR in wcscmp function without casting ?**

As I know from MSDN there is no explicit cast operator for CComBSTR ( while exists for _bstr_t) 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Technically no, a `BSTR` can store `L"str2\0foo"`.  Which will make `wcscmp()` decide for a match, you'll have to compare string lengths as well to avoid this failure mode.

`CComBSTR` overrides operator==() which does the Right Thing, might as well use it:

```
CComBSTR bs1=L"str1";
if (bs1 == L"str2"))
{ 
    // etc..
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is safe to rely on automatic casting from `CComBSTR` to `const WCHAR*` with the only exception that `NULL` is valid value for `BSTR`, and `NULL` argument is **NOT** a valid argument for `wcscmp` [causing invalid parameter handler to be called](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#remarksToggle) by runtime.

As long and you are sure that your `BSTR` value raw/wrapped is non-NULL, you can safely cast.

As others pointed out, beware of embedded zero characters which are terminators `WCHAR*` strings, however might be a part of BSTR payload due to existence of explicit string length (in the value prefix).

FYI also, that `CComBSTR`'s `operator ==` does the comparison internally using [`VarBstrCmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.

Comment: +1. The two dangers are embedded `L'\0'` characters and `BSTR(NULL)` "empty" strings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, BSTRs are null terminated in addition to being length prefixed, and [there is a conversion from CComBSTR to BSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dbyydwx6%28v=vs.80%29) (via the `m_str` member).

You can thus use either `wcscmp(bs1, L"str2")` or `wcscmp(bs1.m_str, L"str2")`, which are equivalent.

However, BSTRs may embed null characters, beware. Using `wcscmp(bstr1, bstr2)` may not do what you want, if the strings are only equal up to the first null character.

Comment: Wouldn't it be technically no, it is not safe because BSTR can embed null characters?

Comment: @0A0D: if you know that you don't embed null characters into BSTRs (which is reasonable to assume in some contexts), it is safe. Otherwise, it is simply incorrect (but safe anyway, depending on how you define "safe"). Better, as Hans suggests, is to simply use `CComBSTR::operator==`.